# Why is redis or other required for socket.io

Tags: sockets, redis, socket.io

I'm currently using Heroku auto scale for my servers. And I need to setup a scalable app using [socket.io](https://socket.io/) to allow instant updates of data (bear in mind that it's only for updating the frontend displays, no data is processed).

The way I was going to set it up was as follows:
[image: sample socket setup]

In the image, all the servers have a socket connection to the "main" socket.io server and to the user.
A user would do an action through an API, the server would do its' thing (save to mondoDB or compute...) and pass it to a "main" socket.io server through its socket.io connection but would not send anything back to the user. The "main" server would receive the request through the socket.io connection and emit it back to the servers, which would then emit it to their users.

So the flow would be: User > Server > Main socket.io server > Server > User

My questions are:

1. Would this work?
2. Why do all the docs refer to db type `redis`?

Comment: Redis or another message queue does the job of "main server" in your diagram, allow syncing across multiple server instances.

Comment: oh, I wasn't seeing it like that. Interesting. Thanks.